# Fetch News Feed of Users Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been with trying to fetch news feed using test users account meanwhile according facebook it have all permissions .But i am failed to do so .I am not sure about facebook terms .Here is my whole code Which quite working Fine But its not returning Null response array in News Feed response. My script.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1476612739307123', // App ID

      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });


    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
    {
     if (response.status === 'connected') 
    {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Connected to Facebook";
        //SUCCESS

    }    
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
    {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Failed to Connect";

        //FAILED
    } else 
    {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Logged Out";

        //UNKNOWN ERROR
    }
    }); 

    };

    function Login()
    {

        FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) 
           {
                getUserInfo();


            } else 
            {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
         },{scope: 'publish_actions', 
    return_scopes: true});


    }

  function getUserInfo() {
        FB.api('/me', {fields: 'id,link,name,first_name,last_name,email,gender'},function(response) {
            console.log(response);

      var str="<b>Name</b> : "+response.name+"<br>";
          str +="<b>First Name</b> : "+response.first_name+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Last Name</b> : "+response.last_name+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Link: </b>"+response.link+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Username:</b> "+response.gender+"<br>";
          str +="<b>id: </b>"+response.id+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Email:</b> "+response.email+"<br>";
          str +="<input type='button' value='Get Photo' onclick='getPhoto();'/>";
          str +="<input type='button' value='Logout' onclick='Logout();'/>";
          document.getElementById("details").innerHTML=str;

    });
    }
    function getPhoto()
    {
      FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {

          var str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+=str;
          });

                 FB.api(
                "/me/feed",
                {
                    "filter":"nf"
                }

                ,function (response) {
                  if (response && !response.error) {
                   console.log(response);
                  } else{ console.log(response.error); alert();}

                }
            );

    }
    function Logout()
    {
        FB.logout(function(){document.location.reload();});
    }

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
```

Cosole Returned Response Array

```
data[]
```

My html Code:

```
<div id="status">
 Click on Below Image to start the demo: <br/>
<img src="http://hayageek.com/examples/oauth/facebook/oauth-javascript/LoginWithFacebook.png" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="Login()"/>
```

Please answer about facebook permissions. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can try whatever you want  on Facebook graph explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/. Once you verified your intention there, you can start writing js code.

Comment: You can't read people's news feed any more. You can only read the user's own timeline.